Highest weight in $\mathfrak{p}$ as a $\mathfrak{k}$-module
Let $\mathfrak{g}_0$ be a noncompact real simple Lie algebra. Fix a Cartan involution $\theta$ of $\mathfrak{g}_0$, which gives a Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g}_0=\mathfrak{k}_0+\mathfrak{p}_0$. Write $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$ for the complexification. Fix a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}$ in $\mathfrak{k}$ and a positive system $\Delta$ for $(\mathfrak{k},\mathfrak{t})$. Regard $\mathfrak{p}$ as a $\mathfrak{k}$-module via the adjoint action. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is irreducible as a $\mathfrak{k}$-module, then write $\beta$ for the highest weight in $\mathfrak{p}$; otherwise, $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_++\mathfrak{p}_-$, and write $\beta$ for the highest weight in $\mathfrak{p}_+$.
Suppose that $\alpha_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ are all simple roots for $\Delta$. Since $\beta$ is dominant integral with respect to $\Delta$, $\beta$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$-linear combination of the fundamental weights. Moreover, since each fundamental weight is a $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq0}$-linear combination of $\alpha_i$, $\beta$ is a $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq0}$-linear combination of $\alpha_i$; that is, $\beta=\sum\limits_{i}r_i\alpha_i$ for $r_i\in\mathbb{Q}_{\geq0}$.
However, it seems true that actually all coefficients $r_i>0$. Is there any theoretical way to prove it? In fact, if $\mathfrak{k}$ is a simple Lie algebra (for example when $\mathfrak{g}_0=\mathfrak{sp}(n,\mathbb{R})$), then it is true because any fundamental weight is a $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$-linear combination of $\alpha_i$.
But when $\mathfrak{k}$ is not simple, for example, $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{so}(p,q)$ and $\mathfrak{k}=\mathfrak{so}(p)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(q)$, the root system $\Delta$ is decomposed as two mutually orthogonal pieces $\Delta_1\cup\Delta_2$. Might it happen that $\beta$ is the combination of simple roots only in $\Delta_1$?

Doesn't your last sentence just prove it regardless of whether $\mathfrak{k}$ is simple so long as it is semisimple (so we can define weights), $\mathfrak{p}$ is an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{k}$ and isn't trivial as a vector space (e.g. when $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is compact) or trivial as a representation (which can't happen as that would make $\mathfrak{k}$ an ideal).
The key being that it can't be trivial for any simple ideal of $\mathfrak{k}$ as that would then be an ideal of the whole of $\mathfrak{g}$.
I suppose we would need to quickly consider the case that $\mathfrak{g}$ is not simple (i.e. that $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is simple but not absolutely simple) but you can quickly see that the real parts of the ideals in those cases are always non-compact and can't be in $\mathfrak{k}$
We can even extend this to the case $\mathfrak{k}$ is reductive if we just look at it as a representation of the semisimple part.
Edit: I will try to make my argument a little clearer.
Firstly we should eliminate the case $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is compact because then $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k}$ and $\mathfrak{p} = \{0\}$ which clearly doesn't work.
So assume $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is noncompact.
Since $\mathfrak{k}$ is compact it has to be reductive so that $\mathfrak{k} = \mathfrak{k}_1  \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathfrak{k}_n \oplus \mathfrak{a}$ where each $\mathfrak{k}_i$ is a simple ideal and $\mathfrak{a}$ is the centre. We note for each simple Lie algebra that  each fundamental weight is a positive combination of the simple roots (I don't actually have a source for that but you have quoted it so I will use it) and thus the only dominant weight which isn't is $0$. In other words the only representation which doesn't have a highest weight of that form is the trivial representation.
If $\mathfrak{p}$ is trivial for some $\mathfrak{k}_i$ then $[\mathfrak{k}_i, \mathfrak{p}] = 0$ but we already know $[\mathfrak{k}_i, \mathfrak{k}_j] = 0$ and $[\mathfrak{k}_i, \mathfrak{a}] = 0$. This immediately implies $[\mathfrak{k}_i, \mathfrak{g}] \subseteq \mathfrak{k}_i$ so $\mathfrak{k}_i$ is an ideal and $\mathfrak{g}$ is not simple.
There are simple Lie algebras whose complexifications are not simple but they are of very specific type. Specifically they are complex simple Lie algebras viewed over the real numbers and we have a decomposition into simple ideals of the form $\mathfrak{g} \cong \mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_0$. In that case, $\mathfrak{k}_0$ is a compact real form. In fact $\mathfrak{k}$ will be isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}_0$ in this case but will sit as a diagonal copy and is not an ideal itself. It is simple but not an ideal so doesn't break my above argument.
Thus $\mathfrak{p}$ cannot be trivial for $\mathfrak{k}$ or any simple ideal. If it is irreducible its highest weight is therefore non-zero and dominant for each simple ideal and by our claim that means its highest weight is a positive combination of simple roots.
I believe that $\mathfrak{p}$ must be irreducible but the only proof I can come up with off the top of my head is using that all maximal abelians in $\mathfrak{p}_0$ are conjugate under the appropriate Lie subgroup corresponding to $\mathfrak{k}_0$ which seems a bit like overkill.

My last sentence means that if $\mathfrak{k}$ is simple, then the conclusion is true, because in this case, $\Delta$ is an irreducible root system, and any fundamental weight is a positive combination of all simple roots. However, when $\mathfrak{k}$ is not simple, for example, $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{so}(p,q)$ and $\mathfrak{k}=\mathfrak{so}(p)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(q)$, the root system $\Delta$ is decomposed as two orthogonal pieces $\Delta_1\cup\Delta_2$. Might it happen that $\beta$ is the combination of simple roots in $\Delta_1$?

@Hebe No because then it would be trivial for the other simple ideal which you could then show must be an ideal of the whole of $\mathfrak{g}$ which means $\mathfrak{g}$ is not simple (as I mentioned technically you need to worry about $\mathfrak{g}_0$ not being absolutely simple but it isn't hard to rule those out

@Hebe I will edit my answer to make my argument more clear

Thanks. If  the component of $\beta$ in $\mathfrak{k}_i$ is zero, the weight vector of $\beta$ forms a trivial representation of $\mathfrak{k}_i$, but it seems not so obvious to conclude that $[\mathfrak{k}_i,\mathfrak{p}]=0$.

@Hebe But that's exactly what a trivial representation is.

Denote by $\mathfrak{p}\beta$ the weight space corresponding to $\beta$. Then $\mathfrak{p}\beta$ is a trivial representation of $\mathfrak{k}i$, and then $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}\beta\oplus U$ as a representation of $\mathfrak{k}_i$. How do you show that $U$ is a direct sum of trivial representations of $\mathfrak{k}_i$ so that $[\mathfrak{k}_i,U]=0$?

@Hebe but $\beta$ is the highest weight not just some random weight

Yes, I understand what you mean. Any dominant integral weight in $U$ is in the form of $\beta$ minus a positive combination of simple roots NOT in $\mathfrak{k}_i$, right?

I think that you are right, but I am confused with the detailed proof.

@Hebe But $0$ minus any simple roots is not a dominant weight

@Hebe I think you are using the term highest weight too loosely. Firstly we can't really refer to a single "highest" weight when the representation is not irreducible. You can have several different vectors which are killed by the action of any positive root vectors but their weights do not have to be comparable so you can't decide which is "highest" among them. I see you have edited your question a little to try to account for this but you don't explain with irreducible piece $\mathfrak{p}_+$ would even refer to.

Yes, when $\mathfrak{p}$ is irreducible, as you said, any other weight is $0$ minus simple roots. When $\mathfrak{p}$ is reducible, things seem easier, because in this case, $\mathfrak{k}$ has the same rank as $\mathfrak{g}$. Thus, $\mathfrak{t}$ is also a Cartan subalgebra in $\mathfrak{g}$. Hence, $\beta$ is the maximal root for $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{t})$, which by structure of root system, is a positive combination of all simple roots.
